# Is their a way to find the closest number to 0 in an Array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I've got an array like that

```
var tideArray = new Array(); 
tideArray.push({tide:"haute1", difference: "-14"});  
tideArray.push({tide:"haute2", difference: "-3"});  
tideArray.push({tide:"basse1", difference: "-9"});  
tideArray.push({tide:"basse2", difference: "4"}); 

tideArray.sortOn("difference", Array.NUMERIC); 
trace(tideArray[0].tide);
```

For now, it's choosing the minimum number (-14) but I'd like to choose the closest number to 0.

Is there a way to do that ?

**EDIT**

I've tried that :

```
trace(closestToZero(tideArray)); 


function closestToZero(a:Array):int  
{  
    var curDelta:int = Math.abs(0 - a[0].difference);  
    var curIndex:int = 0;  

    for(var i:int = 1; i < a.length; i++){  
        var thisDelta:int = Math.abs(0 - a[i].difference);  
        if(thisDelta < curDelta){  
            curIndex = i;  
        }  
    }  

    return curIndex;  
}
```

But it seems that there is a mistake somewhere because the trace result is `3` (so it means that it's telling me that "`basse2`" (`4`) is the closest to 0... But, as you can see, it's "`haute2`" (`-3`) the closest).

Comment: The mistake in your `closestToZero` function is that you don't update your `curDelta` together with `curIndex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be more efficient to simply loop over the array to find the item with the (absolute) minimum `difference` value:

```
if (tideArray.length > 0)
{
    var minItem: Object = tideArray[0];
    for (var index:int = 1; index < tideArray.length; index++)
    {
        if (Math.abs(tideArray[index].difference) < Math.abs(minItem.difference))
        {
            minItem = tideArray[index];
        }
    }
    trace(minItem.tide);
}
```

Comment: If I give the same name to each `tide`, is there a way to detect which index is `minItem.tide` in the array ? (in this example, the index would be `1`)

Comment: I've tried `tideArray.indexOf(minItem.difference)` but the output is -1, so the index wasn't found...

Comment: @steph45 if you need the index afterwards you could simply save it during the loop, but `tideArray.indexOf(minItem)` should work too.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
var tideArray = new Array(); 
...
function sortMyArray(a,b):int {
    if (Math.abs(a) < Math.abs(b)) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (Math.abs(a) > Math.abs(b)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
tideArray.sort(sortMyArray);
```

## Edit :

For your array.

```
function sortMyArray(a,b):int {

    if (Math.abs(a.difference) < Math.abs(b.difference)) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (Math.abs(a.difference) > Math.abs(b.difference)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm...don't think so. I've paste your code, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: My code sorts the array if this is an int array. You just have to adapt it.

Comment: Very sorry, but I still don't understand this code (call me newbie if you want but I'm looking for a precise answer to be honest). When I apply this code, nothing is traced, nothing is returned. If you have an example with a trace or something returned, it would be great. If not, no worries, I'll wait to find a way or that someone would show me. Thank you anyway for your time.

Comment: 'Math.abs(0 - a[i].difference)' is exactly equal to 'Math.abs(a[i].difference)' and why don't you store your values as int but as string ?